# Ember, Ember Data and MongoDB's _id

Tags: mongodb, ember.js, mongoose, ember-data

I've seen this question talked about but I'm still having issues with manhandling Mongo's `_id` into `id`.  I'm using mongoose as my ORM and while it has virtuals I can't seem to get it to work properly.  Below is what I have in my mongoose model.

**Attempt To Fix From The Backend**

```
mongoose = require 'mongoose'
Schema = mongoose.Schema
ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId

ApartmentSchema = new Schema
  body: String
  date: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
  deleted: {type: Boolean, default: false}
  saved: {type: Boolean, default: false}
  visited: {type: Boolean, default: false}
  email: String
  phoneNumber: String
  href: String

ApartmentSchema.virtual('id').get -> return @_id

module.exports = mongoose.model 'Apartment', ApartmentSchema
```

When I create a new instance of this model in express I can do a look up like `apt.id` and get the id back but when I send the response down to the client, I just have `_id` and not `id`.

The second solution I tried was to create a computed property for `id` but for whatever reason ember does not like this. There are 2 problems here. Ember does not respect a computed property called `id` or at least not anymore.  This is what my ember-data model looks like.

**Attempt To Fix It From The Frontend**

```
App.Apartment = DS.Model.extend({
  body: DS.attr('string'),
  date: DS.attr('date'),
  deleted: DS.attr('boolean'),
  saved: DS.attr('boolean'),
  visited: DS.attr('boolean'),
  email: DS.attr('string'),
  phone: DS.attr('string'),
  _id: DS.attr('string'),
  id : function () {
    return this.get('_id')
  }.property('_id')
});
```

In my template below, nothing renders for the id.

```
{{#each apartment in controller}}
    <li>{{apartment.body}} | {{apartment.date}} | {{apartment.href}} {{apartment.id}}</a>  {{#linkTo 'apartment' apartment }} View {{/linkTo}} </li>
{{/each}}
```

The `linkTo` helpers work but the url has null where the id should be.  This results in breaking of the backbutton and loading the data multiple times.  Below is my router for some context.

```
App.Router.map(function(){
  this.resource('apartments', function (){
    this.resource('apartment', { path: ':apartment_id' } );
  });
});
```

Changing the name of my computed `id` property to something like `foo` and then changing my router to `path: ':apartment_foo'` results in urls that have the object reference in the url eg: `#/apartments/<App.Apartment:ember357:null>`.

It's stuff like this that kind of erks me about ember.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As of Ember 1.0.0-rc 1 and Ember Data revision 11, this seems to be the best way to resolve this.

```
App.Adapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  serializer: DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
    primaryKey: function(type){
      return '_id';
    }
  })
});

App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  revision: 11,
  adapter: 'App.Adapter'
});
```

Comment: For me this changes the `null` part of the route to `[object Object]` since the BSON object ID serializes as an object (e.g. `"_id":{"$oid": "5147130ffddd310aeb000001"}`). Was there a fix in your original question that turns that into a string?

Answer (score 7):

As of Ember Data - Version: v1.0.0-beta.2, I was able to do the following:

```
App.ApplicationSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  primaryKey: "_id"
});
```

I'm pretty new to Ember, so this might not be the best method, but it worked!

Comment: After searching for hours, this is the only one that worked for me, thanks

Comment: Ember data has reduced the number of accessible methods recently this doesn't appear to be documented but the primary key attribute is access through [this private method](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v1.0.0-beta.3/packages/ember-data/lib/serializers/rest_serializer.js#L162).

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem as Chris with an id looking something like this:

```
"_id":{"$oid":"52772aa44f6c6c5dd0000000"}
```

Adding the $oid part to claptimes' solution worked for me.

```
App.ApplicationSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  primaryKey: "_id.$oid"
});
```

Comment: Almost works for me, but it seems the id is still not returning (although all the other data comes back).

Comment: I am having a similar problem between Mongodb and ember-data incase anyone wants to have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20544371/ember-data-1-0-0-activemodeladapter-error-include-an-id-in-a-hash-passed-to-p

Answer (score 2):

Since the migration to Ember-CLI, this process has changed slightly. You now want to do this:

1. From the Ember-CLI project command line:

   ```
   ember g serializer application
   ```
2. Make your newly created serializer look like this:

   ```
   import DS from 'ember-data';

   export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
     primaryKey: '_id'
   });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

As of Ember 2.0.0 the proper way to normalize Mongo IDs is to use the `extractId` in the serializer. Here's an example for RESTSerializer running against a Rails/Grape API:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  isNewSerializerAPI: true,
  extractId: function (modelClass, resourceHash) {
    return resourceHash.id.$oid;
  }
});
```

Note that you have to set `isNewSerializerAPI` to `true` for this to work.

For your need, you could try to change to `resourceHash._id.$id` or whatever else works for you. If you're unsure, try `console.log(resourceHash)` to inspect the data.