# ember-data-1.0.0 activemodeladapter error include an `id` in a hash passed to `push`

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-router

I am using ember-data and the activemodel adapter with rails and mongoid(mongodb) in the backend. Whenever I make a request to my rails app, emberjs displays the returned data but in chrome developer console it displays:

```
Assertion failed: You must include an `id` in a hash passed to `push`
```

**the problem reproduced in a jsfiddle**

I have reproduced the problem in this **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VRbtG/1/)**. You can see a different version of thesame **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VRbtG/)** working when I use **id** instead of **_id**.

**Payload sent by the backend**

ActiveModel adapter converts the snake_case **start_date** to camel-case. I have added some custom code to ember-data rest-serializer to convert **_id** to **id** and that code is pasted lower down in this question.

```
    {"schedules":[

       {
         "_id":"529f38596170700787000000",
         "name":"Hair styling",
         "start_date":"2013-12-12"
       }

     ]}
```

Now though the returned **payload** includes an **id**, if I go into the google cgrome console and run the commmands below and access the **_data**, it shows the **id** is undefined.

```
 a = App.__container__.lookup("controller:schedules")
 b = a.get('content')
```

I f use the disclosure arrows in the console and dig into the **_dat** object, this is what I see

```
 _data: Object
   id: undefined
```

**Custom serializer code**

I extended the activemodeladapter to convert mongodb's _id to id and to set it as primary key.

```
App.ApplicationSerializer = DS.ActiveModelSerializer.extend({
   primaryKey: '_id',

   normalize: function(type, hash, prop) {
      this.normalizeMongoidId(hash);
      return this._super(type, hash, prop);
   },

   normalizeMongoidId: function(hash){
     var json = { id: hash._id };
     delete hash._id;

     //hash.id = hash._id;
     //delete hash._id;
   }

  /*
   serialize: function(record, options){
     var json = this._super(record, options);

      json.schedule._id  = json.record.id;

      delete json.record.id
      return json;
   }
  */ 
});
```

**The ember-data model**:

```
App.Schedule = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  organization: DS.belongsTo('organization')
});
```

**Here is my emberjs router**

```
App.Router.map(function(){ 
  this.resource('schedules', {path: "/schedules"}, function(){ 
   this.resource('schedule', {path: "/:schedule_id"}, function(){});   

  }); 
});
```

**The emberjs route defination**:

```
 App.SchedulesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
   model: function(){
    return this.store.find('schedule');  
   }
 });
```

**emberjs stack trace**

```
   Assertion failed: You must include an `id` in a hash passed to `push`   application.js:31601
  (anonymous function) application.js:31601
  Ember.assert application.js:28431
  DS.Store.Ember.Object.extend.push application.js:69415
  (anonymous function) application.js:69483
  Ember.EnumerableUtils.map application.js:30115
  DS.Store.Ember.Object.extend.pushMany application.js:69482
  (anonymous function) application.js:69839
  invokeCallback application.js:36783
  (anonymous function) application.js:36838
  EventTarget.trigger application.js:36621
  (anonymous function) application.js:36921
  DeferredActionQueues.flush application.js:34001
  Backburner.end application.js:34092
  Backburner.run application.js:34131
  Ember.run application.js:34489
  hash.success application.js:74468
  fire application.js:3049
  self.fireWith application.js:3161
  done application.js:8236
  callback
```

Thanks

Comment: can you give full stack trace of error and response given by server to browser

Comment: The ember error is strange but from the log you have it looks like the error is on the Rails server (respond with error 500), could you please give us your `schedulers_controller.rb` ?

Comment: @AdrienCoquio the full **schedules_controller.rb** is pasted there under the section titled **going from emberjs to rails**

Comment: @Hardik127, the stack trace from the emberjs side is pasted underneath the question. For the rails side, what I pasted before is all the stack trace that was returned.  I inspected the object returned in the chrome console and it had no **id** even the json it received had an id. this is the payload **{"schedules":[{"id":{"$oid":"529f38596170700787000000"},"name":"Hair styling","description":null,"start_date":"2013-12-12","end_date":null,"organization":null}]}**

Comment: I have reproduced the unresolved problem in a jsfiddle because I have solved all the backend related issues. However, the emberjs error is still being thrown. Here is the **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VRbtG/1/)**. You can see thesame **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VRbtG/)** working when I use **id** instead of **_id**.

Comment: On the server can your serializer convert _id to id ?

Comment: @pixelhandler thanks for contributing. I tried and the error was still return: **You must include an `id` in a hash passed to `push`** and indeed when I inspect the loaded data in the console, it's id is blank. **do you mind playing with the jsfiddle added to my earlier comments to see**

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. In your rails serializer for schedule, (assuming you have one), you should do

```
attributes :id, :name, :start_date
```

and have a

```
has_many :schedule
```

in your SchedulesSerializer. Let me know if this works.