# Ember.js primaryKey: '_id'?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, ember.js, mongoose

There is a distinct possibly I am loosing my mind over this one. Granted, it does not help I am attempting to learn all these technologies pretty much simultaneously. I built an API using  Node.js/Express/Mongoose/MongoDB, and it works. I am attempting to use this REST endpoint in an Ember.js application. The Ember application works with a fixture, so the client is working.

The problem is the REST endpoint is emitting the object id as `_id` and Ember expects and requires `id`. Yes, I have already [searched and located a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15364630/ember-ember-data-and-mongodbs-id) and have tried the solution:

```
WbsEmber.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  serializer: DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
    primaryKey: function(type){
      return '_id';
    }
  }),
  host: 'http://localhost:8080',
  namespace: 'api'
});
```

Reading the [Ember.DS api documentation for the RESTAdapter](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html#property_primaryKey), it appears this should work:

```
WbsEmber.ApplicationSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
    primaryKey: '_id'
});

WbsEmber.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    host: 'http://localhost:8080',
    namespace: 'api'
});
```

However, both keep tossing this error stack in the console.

```
Error while loading route: Error: No model was found for '0'
    at new Error (native)
    at Error.Ember.Error (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/ember/ember.js:910:19)
    at Ember.Object.extend.modelFor (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/ember-data/ember-data.js:9805:33)
    at JSONSerializer.extend.extractArray (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/ember-data/ember-data.js:3172:28)
    at superWrapper (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/ember/ember.js:1292:16)
    at Ember.Object.extend.extractFindAll (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/ember-data/ember-data.js:2380:21)
    at Ember.Object.extend.extract (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/ember-data/ember-data.js:2365:37)
    at http://localhost:9000/bower_components/ember-data/ember-data.js:10396:34
    at invokeCallback (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/ember/ember.js:10013:19)
    at publish (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/ember/ember.js:9683:9)
```

Just for comparison, my fixture looks like the following:

```
WbsEmber.Code.FIXTURES = [
    { id: 0, wbs: 'C04220', name: 'AGSS', type: 'prefix' },
    { id: 1, wbs: 'E5180', name: "ILO", type: 'suffix' },
    { id: 2, wbs: 'C04210', name: 'ARC1', type: 'prefix' },
    { id: 3, wbs: 'E0040', name: ' course preparation', type: 'suffix' },
    { id: 4, wbs: 'C04232', name: 'ARC2', type: 'prefix' },
    { id: 5, wbs: 'E0041', name: 'learn new course', type: 'suffix' },
    { id: 6, wbs: '4710', name: 'instructor labor', type: 'single' },
    { id: 7, wbs: 'ES1028', name: 'tech lead labor', type: 'single' }
];
```

The JSON response from the REST endpoint looks like:

```
[
    {"_id": "53ac3f0d4e29d793d9f53384", "type": "prefix", "name": "UAGI", "wbs": "C04424", "__v": 0},
    {"_id": "53ac3f114e29d793d9f53385", "type": "prefix", "name": "AGSS", "wbs": "C04220", "__v": 0},
    {"_id": "53ac3f154e29d793d9f53386", "type": "prefix", "name": "ARC1", "wbs": "C04210", "__v": 0},
    {"_id": "53ac3f184e29d793d9f53387", "type": "prefix", "name": "ARC2", "wbs": "C04232", "__v": 0}
]
```

The response is directly copied and pasted from the developer tools in Chrome, so the request is successfully being made and the response is making it to the client.

Just for reference, Here are all the packages and respective versions as well.

```
"dependencies": {
    "ember": "1.5.0",
    "handlebars": "1.2.1",
    "ember-data": "1.0.0-beta.7",
    "bootstrap-sass-official": "3.1.1",
    "ember-addons.bs_for_ember": "~0.7.0"
}
```

I cannot seem to, for the life of me, figure out how to get this working. Any suggestions, insight or references to sources potentially solving this issue are welcomed. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct pattern:

```
WbsEmber.ApplicationSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
    primaryKey: '_id'
});

WbsEmber.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    host: 'http://localhost:8080',
    namespace: 'api'
});
```

Your json response should be (or be serialized), into this format:

```
{
  codes: [
    {"_id": "53ac3f0d4e29d793d9f53384", "type": "prefix", "name": "UAGI", "wbs": "C04424", "__v": 0},
    {"_id": "53ac3f114e29d793d9f53385", "type": "prefix", "name": "AGSS", "wbs": "C04220", "__v": 0},
    {"_id": "53ac3f154e29d793d9f53386", "type": "prefix", "name": "ARC1", "wbs": "C04210", "__v": 0},
    {"_id": "53ac3f184e29d793d9f53387", "type": "prefix", "name": "ARC2", "wbs": "C04232", "__v": 0}
  ]
}
```

The transition document is really helpful for some of the nuances in the documentation which is still in flight: https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md

Comment: Awesome, thank you for picking up the nuance in the JSON response I need to fix. As I said earlier, I am building the REST endpoint as well, so now all I need to do is figure out how to do that. If I know what to look for, I can figure it out. Thank you. Also, I did find that transition document. You are right. Even though a lot of it is above my head right now, it most definitely is good stuff.

Comment: I managed to implement your recommendation a few minutes ago. As you likely already well know, it worked instantly. I have been loosing my mind for the better part of two days over this one. You so rock! Thank you for your help. If we are every in the same town, I owe you a beer...or twelve.